# owl carousel: how to show different items on mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, owl-carousel

I have a slider managed by owl carousel.

```
$('.slider .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop:true,
        dots: false,
        margin: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
         nav: true,
         navText: ['<i class="ti-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="ti-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>']
    });
```

Use an html where the image is created by a javascript via data-background attribute which takes the url of the image.

```
<div id="id_comp_xx" class="text-left item bg-img" data-overlay-dark="3" data-background="https//exempleurl.jpg">
<div class="v-middle caption">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <span class="h4">text example</span>
                <h1>text example</h1>
                text example
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to use different images desktopon / mobile and I have no other solution (for technical reasons) than to create 6 item, 3 for mobile and 3 for desktop.

I tried using boostrap class d-none and d-md-block to handle the display but it doesn't work because owl carousel still displays 6 items, but 3 (the ones with display none) show them white (no background).

```
<div id="id_comp_xx" class="text-left item bg-img d-none d-md-block" data-overlay-dark="3" data-background="https//exempleurl_desktop.jpg">
<div class="v-middle caption">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <span class="h4">text example</span>
            <h1>text example</h1>
            text example
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="id_comp_xx" class="text-left item bg-img d-block d-md-none" data-overlay-dark="3" data-background="https//exempleurl_mobile.jpg">
<div class="v-middle caption">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <span class="h4">text example</span>
            <h1>text example</h1>
            text example
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have the question: Is there a way to tell owl carousel that based on the (floating) width of the window it should display only the items that have a specific class and not consider the items that don't have that class and when the width changes ( desktop) then reverse displays those that don't have the class and doesn't display those that do?

Or do you have some other solution to get the result?